# jQuery AJAX call on chrome android - This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, android-chrome

I have implemented a login form which on submit calls jQuery AJAX call to an API to check authentication. This works fine on Chrome for PCs but doesn't work on chrome android. Instead, it returns this message:

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
>   your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

The login form:

```
<form id="loginForm" class="mt-5 col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <!-- Email field -->
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                   @
                </span>
            </div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email"
             name="email" required>
        </div>
        <!-- Password field -->
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password"
             name="password" id="pwdField" minlength="6" required>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="showPwdBtn">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" id="showPwdIcon"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg mt-4">
    </form>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let loginData = getFormDataAsJSON($(this));
    console.log(loginData);
    $.post(
      "/api/login",
      loginData,
      function(res) {
        if (res == true) {
          window.location = "/";
        } else {
          $("#regError").fadeIn("fast");
        }
      },
      "json"
    );
  });
```

The code before the ajax call works fine but it shows the message on the ajax call.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.tech/Enable-JavaScript-on-an-Android-Phone

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wikihow.tech/Enable-JavaScript-on-an-Android-Phone

Make sure you didnt  javscript for you site ..
either remove your site form blocked or clear chrome  data and try

Comment: javascript is enabled and ajax calls on pc browser works but not on android.

Comment: can this be an issue with the hosting provider